# Undestanding Django Multi-tenancy

Tags: django, multi-tenant

My env:
Django + Postgres

I have this case to solution: My models:

ORG -> oneToMany -> BU(business Unit) -> ManyToMany -> departments ->OneToMany ->assets ->a dozen other related to assets.

A Want to implement Multi-tenancy on ORG level, so that every time I create a new ORG everything above is replicate.
In the past Where I using PHP and MYSQL it will be done on query it was horrible and not good to performance.

Thanks

Comment: Please, provide some code so it is possible to replicate the issue and also understand the structure of the models.

Comment: @raratiru  !  I have only this models Like

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of Postgresql schemas. There is a library for django that is specifically designed for it [django-tenant-schemas](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas)